# Migrating US Census GDB file to PostGIS -- ERROR: tables can have at most 1600 columns

Tags: postgis, ogr2ogr, census

I'm working with data from the American Community Survey, provided by the U.S. Census. Specifically, I've downloaded gdb files from [here](https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER_DP/2016ACS/).

I have the gdb file `ACS_2016_5YR_TRACT.gdb` on my server and I'm attempting to create a psql table with the following:

```
ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"host=host port=5432 dbname=db user=user password=password" ACS_2016_5YR_TRACT.gdb -overwrite -progress --config PG_USE_COPY YES
```

The output I get when running the above is a `CREATE TABLE` command with over 1600 columns which it tries to execute but fails with:

```
ERROR:  tables can have at most 1600 columns
```

Has anybody had success loading ACS5 data onto PostGIS? How could I get around this?

I have to imagine this is a common use case for people working with census data... I'm wondering if there is a way to pass flags to ogr2ogr that would allow it to partition the data? Maybe there's a way to increase the column limit in postgresql? I've tried changing the db settings and recompiling, as suggested in other answers, but haven't had much luck. I'm not sure if that's the best way to go about it though.

Comment: I attempted this a while back but ran into similar problems. https://github.com/leehach/census-postgres this was somewhat helpful but also very confusing

Comment: @ziggy, thanks for linking me to the code. Seems like it has potential, but I had a lot of questions too. I figured out another method using the gdb files. I added an answer that explains my solution. Please let me know what you think. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out a way to get the gdb files into a database. Most of the process can be automated, but I'll have to manually prepare some files.

First, run the `ogr2ogr` command that turns the gdb file into database tables, but this time skip failures with the `-skipfailures` flag. Also, be sure to feed it a schema otherwise you'll be overwriting tables if you plan on storing data for multiple years and/or census geographies:

```
ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"host=host port=5432 dbname=db user=user password=password" ACS_2016_5YR_TRACT.gdb -overwrite -progress --config PG_USE_COPY YES -skipfailures -lco SCHEMA=acs_2016_5yr_tract
```

After the command above is run, the gdb data should now mostly be in the database. Check the tables that were created by listing them. Because the tables are named sequentially, you can tell which tables failed to create:

```
geoservice=> \dt acs_2016_5yr_tract.*
                              List of relations
       Schema       |                Name                 | Type  |  Owner
--------------------+-------------------------------------+-------+----------
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | acs_2016_5yr_tract                  | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | tract_metadata_2016                 | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x00_counts                          | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x01_age_and_sex                     | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x02_race                            | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x03_hispanic_or_latino_origin       | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x04_ancestry                        | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x06_place_of_birth                  | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x09_children_household_relationship | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x10_grandparents_grandchildren      | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x11_household_family_subfamilies    | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x12_marital_status_and_history      | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x13_fertility                       | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x14_school_enrollment               | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x15_educational_attainment          | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x16_language_spoken_at_home         | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x18_disability                      | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x21_veteran_status                  | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x22_food_stamps                     | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x26_group_quarters                  | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x99_imputation                      | table | geo_root
(21 rows)
```

---

Next, following [the documentation](https://www.gdal.org/drv_pgdump.html), use `ogr2ogr` to turn the gdb file into an SQL dump. Remember to give it a schema also. Running the following command will create a SQL file called `ACS_2016_5YR_TRACT.sql` which contains all the statements to populate the database:

```
ogr2ogr --config PG_USE_COPY YES -f PGDump ACS_2016_5YR_TRACT.sql ACS_2016_5YR_TRACT.gdb -lco SRID=4269 -lco SCHEMA=acs_2016_5yr_tract
```

After the SQL dump completes, I found the following `grep` command useful for listing out all the tables in the resulting sql file:

```
$ grep -n 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS' ACS_2016_5YR_TRACT.sql
2:DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "acs_2016_5yr_tract"."x00_counts" CASCADE;
74015:DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "acs_2016_5yr_tract"."x01_age_and_sex" CASCADE;
148742:DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "acs_2016_5yr_tract"."x02_race" CASCADE;
223183:DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "acs_2016_5yr_tract"."x03_hispanic_or_latino_origin" CASCADE;
297302:DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "acs_2016_5yr_tract"."x04_ancestry" CASCADE;
371975:DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "acs_2016_5yr_tract"."x05_foreign_born_citizenship" CASCADE;
447676:DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "acs_2016_5yr_tract"."x06_place_of_birth" CASCADE;
522905:DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "acs_2016_5yr_tract"."x07_migration" CASCADE;
598706:DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "acs_2016_5yr_tract"."x08_commuting" CASCADE;
675255:DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "acs_2016_5yr_tract"."x09_children_household_relationship" CASCADE;
749576:DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "acs_2016_5yr_tract"."x10_grandparents_grandchildren" CASCADE;
823957:DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "acs_2016_5yr_tract"."x11_household_family_subfamilies" CASCADE;
898710:DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "acs_2016_5yr_tract"."x12_marital_status_and_history" CASCADE;
973477:DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "acs_2016_5yr_tract"."x13_fertility" CASCADE;
1047888:DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "acs_2016_5yr_tract"."x14_school_enrollment" CASCADE;
1122675:DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "acs_2016_5yr_tract"."x15_educational_attainment" CASCADE;
1197398:DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "acs_2016_5yr_tract"."x16_language_spoken_at_home" CASCADE;
1272277:DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "acs_2016_5yr_tract"."x17_poverty" CASCADE;
1350226:DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "acs_2016_5yr_tract"."x18_disability" CASCADE;
1425127:DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "acs_2016_5yr_tract"."x19_income" CASCADE;
1502128:DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "acs_2016_5yr_tract"."x20_earnings" CASCADE;
1578319:DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "acs_2016_5yr_tract"."x21_veteran_status" CASCADE;
1652892:DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "acs_2016_5yr_tract"."x22_food_stamps" CASCADE;
1727143:DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "acs_2016_5yr_tract"."x23_employment_status" CASCADE;
1802776:DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "acs_2016_5yr_tract"."x24_industry_occupation" CASCADE;
1878891:DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "acs_2016_5yr_tract"."x25_housing_characteristics" CASCADE;
1957314:DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "acs_2016_5yr_tract"."x26_group_quarters" CASCADE;
2031325:DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "acs_2016_5yr_tract"."x27_health_insurance" CASCADE;
2106968:DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "acs_2016_5yr_tract"."x99_imputation" CASCADE;
2181725:DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "acs_2016_5yr_tract"."tract_metadata_2016" CASCADE;
2217196:DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "acs_2016_5yr_tract"."acs_2016_5yr_tract" CASCADE;
```

---

Comparing the database table listing and the output from the SQL file `grep`, we see the first table that failed is `x05_foreign_born_citizenship`.

Because the `grep` output above also lists line numbers, we see that lines 371975 through 447675 of `ACS_2016_5YR_TRACT.sql` contain all the commands to create `x05_foreign_born_citizenship`. (I confirmed this by opening the file, and you may want to confirm yourself a few times. The file is huge though, so it'll be slow going.)

Using the following `sed` command, I can write the lines to a separate file, `x05.txt`, that's smaller and easier to work with:

```
$ sed '371975,447675!d' ACS_2016_5YR_TRACT.sql > x05.txt
```

---

From here on out it's a matter of writing a script that manipulates the `x05.txt` file. What you'll need to do is break up the one large 1600+ column table into multiple tables. I would offer my own script to the community, but can't because my company owns it. I used Python and pandas to handle it. The files are kind of big, so the server I was on kept on having memory errors. I had to do the work locally on 16GB of RAM. Keep that in mind if you run into memory issues... I could have saved processing power if I didn't use pandas, but it simplified a lot of things. YMMV...

---

In general terms, here is how I wrote the script:

You'll see the first part of `x05.txt` is SQL `DROP`, `CREATE`, and `ALTER` statements. The `ALTER` statements are where the columns are added. My script counted the `ALTER` statements and applied the first 1000 to `x_05_00` table, the second 1000 to `x_05_01`, etc. So update all the SQL statements and run them to create your tables and define the fields in the database.

One gotcha: Make sure all your subtables have the `geoid` field.

Next, in `x05.txt`, you'll come to an SQL `COPY` statement which lists the column names. You can parse that string into a `columns` list variable. Back to the file, the next set of lines immediately after the `COPY` statement is the data itself in tab-delimited form. I wrote all the lines of the data to a csv using the `columns` list variable as the csv header. (Originally I tried to read all the data into a dataframe, but it's too much to handle in memory - better to write it to disk.)

I then read the lines from the csv into a pandas dataframe in `chunks`. I was able to slice each chunk by the first 1000 variables, and using `.to_sql` was able to append the data to the `x05_00` table. Similar for the next 1000 variables - those populate the `x05_01` table, etc. Iterate through all the chunks, and you're done.

If your script is correct, then you'll have created something like the following. Also, if scripted correctly, the newly created tables will be indexed with default values, etc.

list tables:

```
geoservice=> \dt acs_2016_5yr_tract.*
                              List of relations
       Schema       |                Name                 | Type  |  Owner
--------------------+-------------------------------------+-------+----------
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | acs_2016_5yr_tract                  | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | tract_metadata_2016                 | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x00_counts                          | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x01_age_and_sex                     | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x02_race                            | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x03_hispanic_or_latino_origin       | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x04_ancestry                        | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x05_00_foreign_born_citizenship     | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x05_01_foreign_born_citizenship     | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x06_place_of_birth                  | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x09_children_household_relationship | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x10_grandparents_grandchildren      | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x11_household_family_subfamilies    | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x12_marital_status_and_history      | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x13_fertility                       | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x14_school_enrollment               | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x15_educational_attainment          | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x16_language_spoken_at_home         | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x18_disability                      | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x21_veteran_status                  | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x22_food_stamps                     | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x26_group_quarters                  | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x99_imputation                      | table | geo_root
(23 rows)
```

table description:

```
geoservice=> \d acs_2016_5yr_tract.x05_00_foreign_born_citizenship
                                            Table "acs_2016_5yr_tract.x05_00_foreign_born_citizenship"
   Column    |         Type          | Collation | Nullable |                                       Default
-------------+-----------------------+-----------+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 objectid    | integer               |           | not null | nextval('acs_2016_5yr_tract.x05_00_foreign_born_citizenship_objectid_seq'::regclass)
 geoid       | character varying(19) |           |          |
 b05001e1    | double precision      |           |          |
  ...
  ...
  ...

 b05006pre12 | double precision      |           |          |
Indexes:
    "x05_00_foreign_born_citizenship_pk" PRIMARY KEY, btree (objectid)


geoservice-> \d acs_2016_5yr_tract.x05_01_foreign_born_citizenship
                                            Table "acs_2016_5yr_tract.x05_01_foreign_born_citizenship"
   Column    |         Type          | Collation | Nullable |                                       Default
-------------+-----------------------+-----------+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 objectid    | integer               |           | not null | nextval('acs_2016_5yr_tract.x05_01_foreign_born_citizenship_objectid_seq'::regclass)
 geoid       | character varying(19) |           |          |
 b05006prm12 | double precision      |           |          |
 ...
 ...
 ...
 b05014m19   | double precision      |           |          |
Indexes:
    "x05_01_foreign_born_citizenship_pk" PRIMARY KEY, btree (objectid)
```

table counts:

```
geoservice=> select count(*) from acs_2016_5yr_tract.x05_00_foreign_born_citizenship;
 count
-------
 74001
(1 row)

geoservice=> select count(*) from acs_2016_5yr_tract.x05_01_foreign_born_citizenship;
 count
-------
 74001
(1 row)
```

**UPDATE:**

All done - I migrated all the 2016 ACS5 gdb files to a PostGIS database. I had to split the tables into 500 columns each to avoid memory issues during processing.

```
geoservice=> \dt acs_2016_5yr_tract.*
                              List of relations
       Schema       |                Name                 | Type  |  Owner
--------------------+-------------------------------------+-------+----------
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | acs_2016_5yr_tract                  | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | tract_metadata_2016                 | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x00_counts                          | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x01_age_and_sex                     | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x02_race                            | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x03_hispanic_or_latino_origin       | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x04_ancestry                        | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x05_00_foreign_born_citizenship     | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x05_01_foreign_born_citizenship     | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x05_02_foreign_born_citizenship     | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x05_03_foreign_born_citizenship     | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x06_place_of_birth                  | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x07_00_migration                    | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x07_01_migration                    | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x07_02_migration                    | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x07_03_migration                    | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x08_00_commuting                    | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x08_01_commuting                    | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x08_02_commuting                    | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x08_03_commuting                    | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x08_04_commuting                    | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x08_05_commuting                    | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x09_children_household_relationship | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x10_grandparents_grandchildren      | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x11_household_family_subfamilies    | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x12_marital_status_and_history      | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x13_fertility                       | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x14_school_enrollment               | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x15_educational_attainment          | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x16_language_spoken_at_home         | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x17_00_poverty                      | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x17_01_poverty                      | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x17_02_poverty                      | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x17_03_poverty                      | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x17_04_poverty                      | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x17_05_poverty                      | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x17_06_poverty                      | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x17_07_poverty                      | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x18_disability                      | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x19_00_income                       | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x19_01_income                       | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x19_02_income                       | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x19_03_income                       | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x19_04_income                       | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x19_05_income                       | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x20_00_earnings                     | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x20_01_earnings                     | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x20_02_earnings                     | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x20_03_earnings                     | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x20_04_earnings                     | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x21_veteran_status                  | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x22_food_stamps                     | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x23_00_employment_status            | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x23_01_employment_status            | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x23_02_employment_status            | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x23_03_employment_status            | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x24_00_industry_occupation          | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x24_01_industry_occupation          | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x24_02_industry_occupation          | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x24_03_industry_occupation          | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x24_04_industry_occupation          | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x25_00_housing_characteristics      | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x25_01_housing_characteristics      | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x25_02_housing_characteristics      | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x25_03_housing_characteristics      | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x25_04_housing_characteristics      | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x25_05_housing_characteristics      | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x25_06_housing_characteristics      | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x25_07_housing_characteristics      | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x25_08_housing_characteristics      | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x26_group_quarters                  | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x27_00_health_insurance             | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x27_01_health_insurance             | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x27_02_health_insurance             | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x27_03_health_insurance             | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x99_imputation                      | table | geo_root
(76 rows)
```

Comment: Good that works! Would recommend planning for 2020 data!!

Comment: I like this workflow so far. I ran the 1st ogr2ogr command where it inserts the FileGDB into postgres with skip failures. I just created the sql dump file but how do you determine how many columns each TABLE is supposed to have?

Comment: @ziggy, not sure what you mean. I'm using postgres which limits me to 1600 columns, so I'm going to break the large 4000+ column table into smaller tables of probably 1000 columns. The files are huge though, so I've been struggling. When I finish, I'll update my answer with some code samples of how I did it.

Comment: @ziggy: I updated my answer with some more details. Sorry I couldn't give the exact script, but I leave things off at a good place to work off of. If you have specific questions, I can answer them here or in a separate Python question on StackOverflow.

Comment: @alfonso awesome, this is very helpful good work

Answer (score 5):

I would definitely re-think how you store your Census data in PostGIS.

The ArcGIS-ready tables are unnecessarily massive, as you're finding out.

We store our census tables separately with geometry living seperate from non-spatial data from the American FactFinder website.

Geometry tables and columns:

- Tracts (GEOID and GEOM)
- BlockGroups (GEOID and GEOM)
- Blocks (GEOID and GEOM)

Non-spatial tables and columns:

- Demographics at Blockgroup Level (GEOID plus all data fields)
- Income at Blockgroup Level (GEOID plus all data fields)
- American Community Survey 2015 updates (GEOID plus all data fields)
- etc. etc.

We also created a seperate schema for the Census data tables.

This way, we can create our OWN derivative datasets when we need them, and customize as we need.

Additionally, PostGIS and a spatial/relational database has allowed me to make Peace with the Census data - no more worrying about truncating leading 0's, relating data easily on GEOID, and really understanding the FactFinder website and working with the CSV's.

Comment: Could you talk a bit about how and from where you collected the data in the non-spatial tables? Earlier, I went about it by making calls to the census API, but I think going about it with ready-made gdb or shp files would be much easier and more reliable. About the spatial data, I collected mine from the Tiger geocoder as a PostGIS extra, as described in the documentation. Thanks.

Comment: Really its a journey into the American FactFinder website - really digging into what you NEED vs. getting 'everything'. We haven't used the API, as manually fetching that data is enough for our planning purposes. Getting these tables in their 'raw' form has proven to be way easier than the pre-cooked GDB's. And yes, the spatial data we collected from TIGER. Let me know if you have any more questions!

Comment: I liked your suggestion, but was overwhelmed since I'm collecting data at the national level with cbsa, tract, and block granularity. I decided to go back to the gdb files and I think I have a good solution. Please check out my answer to the question and let me know what you think. I'll report back with how it went. Thanks.

Comment: Ahhh an ArcGIS-user downvote... love it...