# US Census block boundaries shapefile

Tags: postgis, shapefile, polygon, census

I am searching for a single file of all roughly 11 million US census blocks. Where can I find this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because requests for data (specially open data) should be on opendata.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**
I looked around the Census TIGER repository and found these files which contain the census geographies and their polygons:

https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2018/

**Old Answer:**

Try here:
https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER_DP/2017ACS/

This is the entire ACS data, but the files do contain a listing of the census blocks as well as polygons.

Edit:
I think for your purposes, this is the file you'd need:
`ACS_2017_5YR_BG.gdb.zip`

You can refer to my earlier Q&A here with advice on how to process these files:
https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/301491/105428

You wouldn't have to go through the whole process I detailed as you'd only be interested in a single table. I ran the process for tracts, and I got back some tables like this:

```
geoservice=> \dt acs_2016_5yr_tract.*
                              List of relations
       Schema       |                Name                 | Type  |  Owner
--------------------+-------------------------------------+-------+----------
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | acs_2016_5yr_tract                  | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | tract_metadata_2016                 | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x00_counts                          | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x01_age_and_sex                     | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x02_race                            | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x03_hispanic_or_latino_origin       | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x04_ancestry                        | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x06_place_of_birth                  | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x09_children_household_relationship | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x10_grandparents_grandchildren      | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x11_household_family_subfamilies    | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x12_marital_status_and_history      | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x13_fertility                       | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x14_school_enrollment               | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x15_educational_attainment          | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x16_language_spoken_at_home         | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x18_disability                      | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x21_veteran_status                  | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x22_food_stamps                     | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x26_group_quarters                  | table | geo_root
 acs_2016_5yr_tract | x99_imputation                      | table | geo_root
(21 rows)
```

For you, process your block group file, and don't worry about the errors that come. The only tables you'd be interested in are the block group equivalents of `acs_2016_5yr_tract` and `tract_metadata_2016`.

This answer assumes you have a Postgresql/PostGIS database system set up. Also, there's probably more convenient files out there that don't include the ACS data. Try digging around the Census TIGER websites. I replied with a quick and dirty method I know would work though.

Hopefully that makes sense. I'm happy to respond to follow up comments.